Rive animation with multiple state machine
In rive I created this animation with 3 state machine changes. How do I make to switch from loading to error based on the input I give it?
I managed to create one state:
void _onRiveInit(Artboard artboard) {
final controller = StateMachineController.fromArtboard(
  artboard,
  'State Machine 2',
  onStateChange: _onStateChange,
);
if (controller != null) {
  artboard.addController(controller);
  _input = controller.findInput<bool>(stateMachineStatus) as SMIBool;
}

}
And later in the build method I modify the stateMachineStatus from loading to 'hasError' but animation won't change as I already called the _onRiveInit in
 RiveAnimation.asset(
           'assets/animations/sd.riv',
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
            animations: const [],
            onInit: _onRiveInit,
            controllers: const [],
          ),



maybe you can try creating 3 variables for 3 inputs. I can take a peak  if you have the git repo + rive file link(to verify dataType),

all data types for those are booleans.
I tried with variables, but rive doesn't get called again with the updated variable.

Based on the example from here I was able to change the states of the rive animation: https://github.com/rive-app/rive-flutter/blob/master/example/lib/liquid_download.dart
There should use:
 child: Rive(
             artboard: _riveArtboard!,
            ),

and on the init of the widget call this function to update it's states:
Future<void> _loadRiveFile() async {
final file = await RiveFile.asset('assets/liquid_download.riv');
final artboard = file.mainArtboard.instance();
var controller = StateMachineController.fromArtboard(artboard, 'Download');
if (controller != null) {
  artboard.addController(controller);
  _start = controller.getTriggerInput('Download');
  _progress = controller.getNumberInput('Progress');
}
setState(() => _riveArtboard = artboard);

}
